# JMeter BSF Sampler Response

Tags: javascript, jmeter

Within my JMeter test, I have some HTTP Requests and BSF samplers. In viewing the Results Tree, I'm a little confused by what I see in the `response` portion of the BSF sampler. The request displays my BSF script (in javascript), which is:

```
var jobStatus = vars.get("jobStatus");
if (String(vars.get("jobCompleted")) === "true") {
    if (String(jobStatus) != "completed") {
        vars.put("uploadError", true);
        log.info("ERROR: Job Status did not complete correctly. Reason: " + jobStatus);
    } else {
        log.info("Job completed successfully.");
        vars.put("uploadError", false);
    }
}
```

The response returns this, which I am perplexed by:

`org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@fccc6e`

I'm not exactly sure what this means - the `undefined` portion leads me to believe this is an error I have unknowingly created, though the test and script run fine.

Answer (score 0):

No - this is NOT an issue. It seems to be a correct behavior as Javascript engine does not have anything to return. If there is an ERROR - you can check in the log viewer.

Try this - same as above your script - but i return the value of jobStatus - so that you will not see 'Undefined'

```
var jobStatus = vars.get("jobStatus");
if (String(vars.get("jobCompleted")) == "true") {
    if (String(jobStatus) != "completed") {
        vars.put("uploadError", true);
        log.info("ERROR: Job Status did not complete correctly. Reason: " + jobStatus);
    } else {
        log.info("Job completed successfully.");
        vars.put("uploadError", false);
    }
}
jobStatus;
```